# How to work with CoreData in SwiftUI Preview?

Tags: swift, core-data, swiftui

I have a list with items. When I press on item opened screen with item's detailed but I get preview error. I do something like that, but it's doesn't work:

```
    struct FriendProfile_Previews: PreviewProvider {
        static let moc = PersistenceController.preview.container.viewContext
    
        static var previews: some View {
            let item = Friend(context: moc)
            item.name = "Name"
            item.photo = Data()
            item.about = "About"
            item.card_number = "card_number"
            item.phone_number = "phone_number"
            item.id = UUID()
            
            return NavigationView {
                FriendProfile(friend: item)
                
            }
        }
    }
```

How to do correct fetch data from the Core Data in SwiftUI Preview?

Comment: Add a method to your PersistenceController that always fetches a specific Friend object or create a mock PersistenceController that uses a in memory store and always comes pre-loaded with objects

Comment: @JoakimDanielson how to use this mock PersistenceController in Preview?

Comment: Either the same way you are doing now or add some convenience method to it that returns a Friend object